# Android: How to programmatically get raw data for GPS? (not js or html5 way)

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I'm implementing my app which could get location for users. However, I found LocationManager didn't always work in all devices, you know, there are lots of different Android devices. Then I'm thinking about getting raw gps data and sending it to a location web service to get location back would be better.

After looked around over SO, I failed to get a robust solution, is there any idea? I'm really curious that how some GPS apps in market can work on every device.

**Code Snippet**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener(locationManager);
locationListener.start();
```

Listener,

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

public static int PERMISSION_DENIED = 1;
public static int POSITION_UNAVAILABLE = 2;
public static int TIMEOUT = 3;

protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected boolean running = false;
public MyLocationListener(LocationManager locationManager )
{
    this.locationManager = locationManager;
}


public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location provider '" + provider + "' disabled.");
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Location provider "+ provider + " has been enabled");
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d(TAG, "The status of the provider " + provider + " has changed");
    if (status == 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, provider + " is OUT OF SERVICE");
    }
    else if (status == 1) {
        Log.d(TAG, provider + " is TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, provider + " is AVAILABLE");
    }
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "The location has been updated!");
    Log.d(TAG, "latitude = "+location.getLatitude()+" altitude = "+location.getAltitude());
}

public void start() {

    if (!this.running) {
        if (this.locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null) {
            this.running = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"using gps");
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 600000, 0, this);
        } else {
              Log.d(TAG, "GPS provider is not available.");
        }
    }

    if (!this.running) {
        if (this.locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) != null) {
            this.running = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"using network");
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 600000, 10, this);
        } else {
           Log.d(TAG, "Network provider is not available.");
        }
    }
}

private void stop() {
    if (this.running) {
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        this.running = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Destroy listener.
 */
public void destroy() {
    this.stop();
}
```

Sometimes, onStatusChanged simply got nothing.

Comment: those apps  use LocationManager too

Comment: I don't see how send the data to a server would help you. parsing gps data is not that complex. and locationManager does that for you, even

Answer (score 0):

[`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) is The Only Approach. All devices have Android API - what not all devices have is GPS module inside. But you can check it using `LocationManager` as well.

Comment: I tried one device, neither google map nor my app can locate, but some other apps can, weird...

Comment: Did you try to get positioning info at (more or less) the same time? Maybe satellites were not yet located (blinking GPS symbol in the notification bar)

Comment: I did those tests at the same time. But you know, gps data was not the only source to determine location, so I also tested via wifi in house, still got nothing

Comment: I think that at this point you should post some code. There are too few clues right now to solve the problem.